# creating a default string in my string List

Tags: c#, string, list

So, I'm working with c# and I'm trying to create a Bar graph in the console using strings. So I created a 2D list and gave each slot a default "empty" image.

```
List<List<string>> chart = new List<List<string>>() {"| |"};
```

but when i wrote it out, i got these two error messages in Visual studios

```
Error   1   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Error   2   The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>.Add(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Probably what you are looking for is `List<string>` not `List<List<String>>`

Comment: int[] levels = { 1, 4, 5, 2 };
Console.Write(string.Join("\r\n", Enumerable.Range(levels.Min(), levels.Max()).Reverse().Select(y => string.Join(" ", levels.Select(l => l >= y ? "|" : " ")))));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is

```
List<List<string>> chart = new List<List<string>>() { new List<String>() { "| |" }};
```

since you're creating *list of list of string* (*2D list* as you've put it), not just *list of string*.

Answer (score 0):

When u need to create default string in your List try this:

```
List<string> chart = new List<string>() {"| |"};
```

or if u need initialize default string in your List of `List<string>` try

```
List<List<string>> chart = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string> { "| |" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add List as parameter

```
List<List<string>> chart = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string>{"| |","| |"}};
```